# OS X 10.10.5 Preview App

Tags: macos, preview

Highlight drop down menu is greyed out on OS X 10.10.5 in my preview.app.

I understand that's where the Alpha tool is? Suggestions please for gaining access to that menu command?

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for Instant Alpha?

[image]

Just go to **View** → **Show Markup Toolbar** (<kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>) and select it.

Comment: Exactly. When I go into "Adjust Color" I don't see the Instant Alpha tool....just exposures, hues, etc.

Comment: I just figured it out. It is an icon 2nd from the left in Markup.

Comment: I showed you the screenshot of the markup toolbar where the icon is located, please accept the answer since it solved your question.

Comment: Very odd...you changed the screen shot and edited your answer. You clearly told me to go into "Adjust Color," and I'm the one who told you it was in markup.

Comment: The picture was there all along, the markup toolbar can be invoked with Adjust Color as well but I edited the answer to Show Markup Toolbar instead since it's the more logical solution.

Comment: Untrue. I looked very carefully at it. It was definitely not there.

Comment: A moderator can easily confirm the pic was there, don't be evil. I spent time helping you, my answer is valid even without the pic. You should strive to be constructive, accusing me of lying on a help site is low.